# Cannot use if statement in onSingleClick? Also need PDF loader on doubleclick

Tags: java, android, if-statement, onclick

I have a horizontal scroll view, with several imageviews inside of it. 
If I click once on the images, I want to show a toast. This toast has to be changed depending on a stringvariable that is set in a textview.

If there is a doubleclick on an image, I need to open a new activity that opens a PDF (embedded into the app).

At the moment I have:

```
public class activity_fruit extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("Fruit");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
    textView.setText(((Globals) this.getApplication()).getTaal());

 int fruit1 = R.drawable.kumato;
    ImageView targetImageView1 = findViewById(R.id.img_fruit1);
    targetImageView1.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSingleClick(View v) {
            if(textView.equals("ENG")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "eng single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        if (textView.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nl single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }}

        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "double", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(fruit1)
            .into(targetImageView1);
```

Everything loads just fine, but since adding the if statement to my onSingleClick(), the one tap doesn't work anymore. The double tap works just fine.

As said in the first few lines of this post, I also want to change my double tap code to open a new activity and then open a PDF (that is stored in the app itself) inside the app itself. So any help with that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site! I'll go back over the questions and accept / upvote the helpful answers. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @GhostCat Cool! Thanks :-) 
ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
textView.equals("ENG"))
```

You are comparing the **text view** object with a String. That will always return false!

Instead - retrieve the **text** from the textView - and compare that string with your other strings! As in:

```
textView.getText().equals("ENG")
```

You are like comparing a "box for eggs" with an egg. Instead, you first have to fetch an egg from that box, then you can compare that egg to your other egg.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you so much, also for the added explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of `textView.equals("ENG")`

Use this.

```
if(textView.getText().equals("ENG")) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "eng single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Use This**

```
textView.getText().toString().trim().equals("ENG")
{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "eng single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**instead of**

`textView.equals("ENG")`